# Pass arguments to another function in a different .py file

Tags: python-3.x

I need pass the arguments of a function of `x.py` file to `y.py` file's function and call the `y.py` function from `x.py` file.

auto_rebalance.py:

```
  def handle_team_switch_attempt(self, player, old, new):
        """
        Handles the case where a player switches from spectators to "red", "blue", or "any" team, and
        the resulting teams would be suboptimal balanced.
        :param: player: the player that attempted the switch
        :param: old: the old team of the switching player
        :param: new: the new team that swicthting player would be put onto
        :return: minqlx.RET_NONE if the team switch should be allowed or minqlx.RET_STOP_EVENT if the switch should not
        be allowed, and we put the player on a better-suited team.
        """
        if not self.game:
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        if self.last_new_player_id == player.steam_id and new in ["spectator", "free"]:
            self.last_new_player_id = None

        if self.game.state != "in_progress":
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        if old not in ["spectator", "free"] or new not in ['red', 'blue', 'any']:
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        if "balance" not in self.plugins:
            Plugin.msg("^1balance^7 plugin not loaded, ^1auto rebalance^7 not possible.")
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        gametype = self.game.type_short
        if gametype not in SUPPORTED_GAMETYPES:
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        teams = self.teams()
        if len(teams["red"]) == len(teams["blue"]):
            self.last_new_player_id = player.steam_id
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        if not self.last_new_player_id:
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        last_new_player = Plugin.player(self.last_new_player_id)
        if not last_new_player:
            self.last_new_player_id = None
            return minqlx.RET_NONE

        other_than_last_players_team = self.other_team(last_new_player.team)
        new_player_team = teams[other_than_last_players_team].copy() + [player]
        proposed_diff = self.calculate_player_average_difference(gametype,
                                                                 teams[last_new_player.team].copy(),
                                                                 new_player_team)

        alternative_team_a = [player for player in teams[last_new_player.team] if player != last_new_player] + \
                             [player]
        alternative_team_b = teams[other_than_last_players_team].copy() + [last_new_player]
        alternative_diff = self.calculate_player_average_difference(gametype,
                                                                    alternative_team_a,
                                                                    alternative_team_b)

        self.last_new_player_id = None
        if proposed_diff > alternative_diff:
            last_new_player.tell(f"{last_new_player.clean_name}, you have been moved to "
                                 f"{self.format_team(other_than_last_players_team)} to maintain team balance.")
            last_new_player.put(other_than_last_players_team)
            if new in [last_new_player.team]:
                return minqlx.RET_NONE
            if new not in ["any"]:
                player.tell(f"{player.clean_name}, you have been moved to {self.format_team(last_new_player.team)} "
                            f"to maintain team balance.")
            player.put(last_new_player.team)
            return minqlx.RET_STOP_ALL
```

How do I pass the results of `handle_team_switch_attempt(self, player, old_team, new_team)` to `handle_team_switch_attempt(self, player, old, new)` in `auto_rebalance.py` when `player.put(team)` is called in `team_placement`? I've been told to add `self.plugins['auto_rebalance].handle_team_switch_attempt(self, player, old, new)` after `players.put(team)` but it is not working.

specqueue.py:

```
def handle_team_switch_attempt(self, player, old_team, new_team):
        if self.q_game_info[0] in SUPPORTED_GAMETYPES and new_team != "spectator" and old_team == "spectator":
            teams = self.teams()
            at_max_players = False
            join_locked = False
            self.remove_from_afk(player)
            if self.q_game_info[0] in TEAM_BASED_GAMETYPES:
                if len(teams["red"]) + len(teams["blue"]) >= self.get_max_players():
                    at_max_players = True
                join_locked = self.free_locked
            elif self.q_game_info[0] in NONTEAM_BASED_GAMETYPES:
                if len(self.teams()["free"]) >= self.get_max_players():
                    at_max_players = True
                join_locked = self.red_locked or self.blue_locked
            if self._queue or join_locked or self.game.state in ["in_progress", "countdown"] or\
                    at_max_players:
                self.add_to_queue(player)
                self.remove_from_spec(player)
                self.check_for_opening(0.2)
                self.update_queue_tags()
                return minqlx.RET_STP_ALL

def team_placement(self, player, team, add_queue=False):
        if ENABLE_LOG:
            self.queue_log.info("specqueue team placement: {} put on team {}".format(player, team))
        try:
            player.put(team)
            if add_queue:
                self.add_to_queue_pos(player, 0)
        except Exception as e:
            if ENABLE_LOG:
                self.queue_log.info("specqueue team placement Exception: {}".format([e]))
```

Comment: Well I'm not actually getting an error. The way the specqueue.py deals with handle_team_switch_attempt it calls a function to insert players in a queueing system and then that queueing function checks for open spots on teams to put players in, then calls a function to remove them from queue and then calls a function to put the players in teams. While all of this is happening, handle_team_switch_attempt in the auto_rebalance.py has been processed and returns FALSE. I'm just not sure how to recall handle_team_switch_attempt with the arguments for auto_rebalance

Comment: handle_team_switch is called from a hook team_switch_attempt and that passes the values for the handle_team_switch_attempt arguments.